# Javascript onClick event to open modal

Tags: jquery, modal-dialog, buttonclick

I am using a modal plugin that I discovered from [here](http://github.com/kylefox/jquery-modal) that works great for my application. I make the modal appear by linking to it this way:

```
<a href="#myDiv" rel="modal:open">Make Modal Appear</a>
```

However, I'd like to use the onclick event with a button to make the same plugin work but I can't figure out how to use the "rel=modal:open" code with the onclick event. Without "rel=" command in there, the plugin won't function properly. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean you want an additional button to do open the modal then you could do something like this:

```
<a id="modal-open" href="#myDiv" rel="modal:open">Make Modal Appear</a>
<button id="another-modal-open" onClick="$('#modal-open').trigger('click');">Also Opens Modal</button>
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/aag1wer9/